# Vim EasyMotion: Insert mode after movement?

Tags: vim, plugins, remap

I have remapped the EasyMotion commands `,,w` and `,,b` with the following:

`imap ,w <ESC><leader><leader>w`

`imap ,b <ESC><leader><leader>b`

This way i'm able to use EasyMotion in Insert mode and navigate quickly without entering Normal mode.

Though, after the move, Vim stays in Normal mode (naturally). How can I specify that after EasyMotion's
employment, Vim should enter Insert mode, in order to continue typing without delay?

Thanx!

Comment: Doesn't appending `a` (or `i`) after the mappings work for you?

Comment: Nope. when I press `,w` the EasyMotion is applied (that is the intention of the mapping), but after moving (through the EasyMotion) i result in Normal mode. I guess I have to manipulate EasyMotion itself, but don't know how.

Comment: Just came up to mind: perhaps using `i_CTRL-o` (execute one command, return to insert mode) can be helpful. Although I'm not sure this is the proper way of doing it, with `:inoremap ,, :<C-o>:normal! fs<CR>` you can move the cursor to the nearest `s` in insert mode by pressing `,,`(I'm not familiar with easymotion, so I replaced that with the motion with `f`).

Comment: I feel like this goes against the Vim Way. Why avoid normal mode? I understand you are trying to avoid keystrokes, which is a commendable goal, but where does this imap-ing stop? Are you going to want to do undo's/page motions/case transforms/jumps/deletions/... while in insert mode? The advantage of normal mode is that you spend most of your time in it a it provides you wonderful language to do movements and operations on your text. It be a key stroke or so, but I believe that avoiding normal mode will create some bad habits and will be like swimming upstream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<C-o>` to execute one normal mode command from insert mode. Once this command has been executed, you will be returned to insert mode:

```
imap ,w <C-o><leader><leader>w
imap ,b <C-o><leader><leader>b
```

Comment: Depending on the application it may also be worth adding `<c-g>u` to break up an undo block. e.g. `imap ,w <c-g>u<c-o><leader><leader>w`. See `:h undo-blocks` and `:h i_ctrl-g_u` for mor information.

Comment: very handy. Also for going into insertmode after movement in normal mode: 

    `nmap <Leader>i i<C-o><Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)i`